# Incluindo mais audios em uma function

Tags: funções, áudio

o Daniel, semana passada sugeriu uma function de áudio, que atendeu perfeita ao que eu desejava. Ocorre que tenho necessidade de inserir mais áudios. Dai inclui um #audio3 e fiz as alterações na function. O resultado não é o esperado, ou seja, estou dando play em #audio3, o #audio2 continua...Desculpe, procurei alterar a function, mas não estou tendo êxito.

```js
<!--function do audio -->
   <script>
   $(function(){

    $("#audio1").on('play', function(){
   var pe = $("#audio2").get(0);
   var pe = $("#audio3").get(0);  

   if(pe.paused == false)
     pe.pause();
    });

    $("#audio2").on('play', function(){
   var pe = $("#audio1").get(0);
   var pe = $("#audio3").get(0);  

   if(pe.paused == false)
     pe.pause();
    });
    
    $("#audio3").on('play', function(){
   var pe = $("#audio1").get(0);
   var pe = $("#audio2").get(0);  

   if(pe.paused == false)
     pe.pause();
    });  

  });
    
    
        
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvei alterando a function assim:

```
 <!--function do audio -->
  <script>
        $(function(){

      $("#audio1").on('play', function(){
        var pe = $("#audio2").get(0);

        if(pe.paused == false)
          pe.pause();
      });

      $("#audio1").on('play', function(){
        var pe = $("#audio3").get(0);  

        if(pe.paused == false)
          pe.pause();
      });

      $("#audio2").on('play', function(){
        var pe = $("#audio1").get(0);

        if(pe.paused == false)
          pe.pause();
      });

      $("#audio2").on('play', function(){
        var pe = $("#audio3").get(0);  

        if(pe.paused == false)
          pe.pause();
      });       


      $("#audio3").on('play', function(){
        var pe = $("#audio1").get(0);

        if(pe.paused == false)
          pe.pause();
      });       

      $("#audio3").on('play', function(){
        var pe = $("#audio2").get(0);  

        if(pe.paused == false)
          pe.pause();
      });               


    });



</script>

<!--Fim function audio-->
```

Resultado foi o esperado. Não permite executar duas vezes um áudio, somente um de cada vez.